# MVC - editar familia no recibe el id correcto

Tags: php, html, mysql, mvc

Resulta que tengo una clase llamada familia en al que he preparado las funciones para poder ver, editar, borrar.... (pongo solo editar ya que aquí esta el error).

> clases.php

```
// ----------------------------------- FAMILIA -------------------------------------------------

class Familia
{
   private $id;
   private $familia_productos;
   private $importe_alquiler;
   private $tiempo_alquiler;

   const TABLA = 'familia';

   public function getNombre()
   {
      return $this->familia_productos;
   }

   public function __construct($familia_productos, $importe_alquiler, $tiempo_alquiler, $id = null)
   {
      $this->familia_productos = $familia_productos;
      $this->importe_alquiler = $importe_alquiler;
      $this->tiempo_alquiler = $tiempo_alquiler;
      $this->id = $id;
   }

   public function editar($familia_productos,$importe_alquiler,$tiempo_alquiler,$id)
   {
      $conexion = new Conexion();

      $consulta = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE ' . self::TABLA . ' SET familia_productos = :familia_productos, importe_alquiler = :importe_alquiler, tiempo_alquiler = :tiempo_alquiler WHERE id = :id');
      $consulta->bindParam(':familia_productos', $this->familia_productos);
      $consulta->bindParam(':importe_alquiler', $this->importe_alquiler);
      $consulta->bindParam(':tiempo_alquiler', $this->tiempo_alquiler);
      $consulta->bindParam(':id', $this->id);
      $consulta->execute();

      $conexion = null;
   }


   public static function ver($id)    {
      $conexion = new Conexion();
      $consulta = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' . self::TABLA . ' WHERE id = :id');
      $consulta->bindParam(':id', $id);
      $consulta->execute();
      $registro = $consulta->fetch();
      return $registro;    }
```

Y he creado el archivo editar_familia.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['idadmin']) || $_SESSION['idadmin'] == null) {
    print "<script>alert(\"Acceso inválido!\");window.location='../login/index.php';</script>";
}

include("../../includes/php/clases.php");

if (isset($_POST['guardarperfilFamilia'])) {
    $familia_productos = $_POST['familia_productos'];
    $importe_alquiler = $_POST['importe_alquiler'];
    $tiempo_alquiler = $_POST['tiempo_alquiler'];

    $familia = new Familia($familia_productos, $importe_alquiler, $tiempo_alquiler, $_GET['idadmin']);
    $familia->editar($familia_productos, $importe_alquiler, $tiempo_alquiler, $_GET['idadmin']);

    $mensaje = 'La familia de productos '.$familia->getNombre().' se ha editado correctamente';
}

$familia = Familia::ver($_GET['idadmin']);
foreach ($familia as $item):
    $familia_productos = $item['familia_productos'];
    $importe_alquiler = $item['importe_alquiler'];
    $tiempo_alquiler = $item['tiempo_alquiler'];
endforeach;

include("../../includes/php/datos.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Perfil de <?php echo $familia_productos; ?></title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="" name="description"/>
    <meta content="" name="author"/>

    <!-- ================== BEGIN BASE CSS STYLE ================== -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/css/default/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- ================== END BASE CSS STYLE ================== -->

    <!-- ================== BEGIN PAGE LEVEL CSS STYLE ================== -->
    <link href="../assets/plugins/superbox/superbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../assets/plugins/lity/dist/lity.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- ================== END PAGE LEVEL CSS STYLE ================== -->
    <script src="../../includes/js/funcionesperfil.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- begin #page-loader -->
<div id="page-loader" class="fade show"><span class="spinner"></span></div>
<!-- end #page-loader -->

<!-- begin #page-container -->
<div id="page-container" class="fade page-sidebar-fixed page-header-fixed">
    <!-- begin #header -->
    <?php include "../includes/menutop.php"; ?>
    <?php include "../includes/menu.php"; ?>
    <div class="sidebar-bg"></div>
    <!-- end #sidebar -->

    <!-- begin #content -->
    <div id="content" class="content content-full-width">
        <!-- begin profile -->
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile-header">
                <!-- BEGIN profile-header-cover -->
                <div class="profile-header-cover"></div>
                <!-- END profile-header-cover -->
                <!-- BEGIN profile-header-content -->
                <div class="profile-header-content">
                    <!-- BEGIN profile-header-info -->
                    <div class="profile-header-info">
                        <h4 class="mt-0 mb-1"><?php echo $nombreadmin1; ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END profile-header-info -->
                </div>
                <!-- END profile-header-content -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end profile -->

        <!-- begin panel -->
        <div class="panel panel-inverse">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">Editar familia de productos</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form method="post">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr class="highlight">
                            <td class="field">Nombre del producto</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="familia_productos" value="<?php echo $familia_productos; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="field">Importe de alquiler</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="importe_alquiler" value="<?php echo $importe_alquiler; ?>" class="form-control" /> €</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="field">Tiempo de alquiler</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="tiempo_alquiler" value="<?php echo $tiempo_alquiler; ?>" class="form-control" /> minutos</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="submit" name="guardarperfilFamilia" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Guardar" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- end #content -->

    <!-- begin scroll to top btn -->
    <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon btn-circle btn-success btn-scroll-to-top fade" data-click="scroll-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
    <!-- end scroll to top btn -->
</div>
<!-- end page container -->

<!-- ================== BEGIN BASE JS ================== -->
<script src="../assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../assets/crossbrowserjs/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/crossbrowserjs/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/crossbrowserjs/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="../assets/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/plugins/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/theme/default.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/apps.min.js"></script>
<!-- ================== END BASE JS ================== -->

<!-- ================== BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS ================== -->
<script src="../assets/plugins/superbox/superbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/plugins/lity/dist/lity.min.js"></script>
<!-- ================== END PAGE LEVEL JS ================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

Cuando intento editar una familia esta nunca se muestra, si la familia que tengo en mi base de datos es el identificador 1 en la base de datos aquí se muestra como id 4, por poner un ejemplo, no tengo ningún error con este funcionamiento en ningún otro lugar de mi base de datos, es decir se muestra correctamente la familia y sus columnas, ademas puedo trabajar con otras tablas enlazadas a la tabla familia sin ningún problema y coge el id correcto, pero a la hora de editar la familia no funciona y no se muy bien cual es mi error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el trozo de archivo donde se puede ver el listado de familias y editarlo llamado

> listado_familia.php

```
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table id="data-table-combine" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-td-valign-middle">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="1%"></th>
                                <th class="text-nowrap">Nombre de la Familia</th>
                                <th class="text-nowrap">Importe Alquiler</th>
                                <th class="text-nowrap">Tiempo Alquiler</th>
                                <th class="text-nowrap">Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <?php
                            $familias = Familia::recuperarTodos();
                            foreach ($familias as $familia) :
                            ?>

                                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                    <td width="1%" class="f-s-600 text-inverse"><?php echo $familia['id']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $familia['familia_productos']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $familia['importe_alquiler']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $familia['tiempo_alquiler']; ?></td>

                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <a class="green" href="editar_familia.php?idadmin=<?php echo $familia['id']; ?>" title="Ver / Editar Familia">
                                            <i class="fas fa-lg fa-fw m-r-10 fa-edit"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <a class="red" href="javascript:;" onclick="aviso('listado_familia.php?idadmin=<?php echo $familia['id']; ?>'); return false;" title="Eliminar Familia">
                                            <i style="color: red;" class="fas fa-lg fa-fw m-r-10 fa-times"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- end panel-body -->
```

Comment: @Marcos este proyecto ya venia hecho así, nose porque lo pusieron pero en toda la web esta igual y parece que funciona correctamente. es decir hace como que comprueba si estas logueado pero después tambien le pasa el id del producto, realmente no me atrevi a cambiarlo porque funcionaba.

Comment: @Marcos ya te lo he adjuntado

Comment: No veo nada raro, salvo esto `foreach ($familia as $item):`. El método `ver` devuelve un solo registro, por lo que el `foreach` no tiene sentido. Si sacas eso tendrías que cambiar, por ejemplo, `$familia_productos = $item['familia_productos'];` a `$familia_productos = $familia['familia_productos'];`

Comment: @Marcos ya muestra correctamente el nombre de la familia y su identificador pero sigue sin cargar el panel de edición de dicha familia. ha quedado de este modo $familia = Familia::ver($_GET['idadmin']);

    $familia_productos = $familia['familia_productos'];
    $importe_alquiler = $familia['importe_alquiler'];
    $tiempo_alquiler = $familia['tiempo_alquiler'];

Comment: @Marcos pues estoy un poco perdida con el problema realmente, porque pensaba que era del id, pero sigo sin entender porque no se muestra la página y sigue cargando eternamente. debería coger el id correcto verdad?

Comment: @Marcos no, a ver tiene un script que cuando no se puede ver la página o esta cargando sale un circulito que da vueltas, pues bueno se queda eternamente en este circulito, y no muestra la página, debido a que algo en esa página esta mal al recuperar datos, el nombre aparece correctamente en la pestaña superior y en la url parece ser que se asigna correctamente id, pero nunca muestra contenido, debido a algun error.

Comment: Tengo un archivo similar a este, llamado editar_productos.php que es idéntico a este, la única diferencia es que el otro si funciona y este no. pero pensaba que era por el identificador ya que editar_productos existia de antes y editar_familia es un nuevo archivo

Comment: Evidentemente esta ocurriendo un error de `Javascript`. Vas a tener que abrir el `DevTools` para identificarlo. Mientras tanto, si borras/comentas el elemento `<div id="page-loader"` vas a poder ver el documento.

Comment: @Marcos Muchas gracias!!! tenias toda la razón, voy a ver como arreglo este problemita muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Si usas Ajax o Fetch de Javascript para mandar a buscar los datos al servidor desde el cliente, conviene que muestres esa parte de tu código, puede que ahí esté el problema de que se  quede como cargando en vez de mostrar los datos ya venidos del servidor.